# Understanding XML::Twig"s wrap_in

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I am looping through a twig's descendants, and in this loop I want to create new twigs to output later. Those new twigs are basically wrapped versions of the current looped item. Something like this:

```
# $twig already exists.
my @descendants = $twig->root->first_child->descendants_or_self;
foreach (@descendants) {
  $_->root->wrap_in('tree');

  my $treetop = XML::Twig->new()->set_root($_);

  $treetop->root->wrap_in('trees', treebank => {
    id => 'someid'
  });

  if (exists $hash{'somekey'}) {
    $treetop->root->set_att(c => 'd');
  }
}
```

An example of `$_->sprint` in the loop:

```
<node begin="0">
  <node a="b"></node>
</node>
```

However, the result of this (after the last if-clause) is (`$treetop->sprint`):

```
<node begin="0" c="d">
  <node a="b"></node>
</node>
```

In other words, the attribute is added to the initial 'root', and no wrapping happens. But what I'm trying to achieve is:

```
<treebank id="someid" c="d">
  <trees>
    <tree>
      <node begin="0">
        <node a="b"></node>
      </node>
    </tree>
  </trees>
</treebank>
```

Interestingly, when I call `$_->root` I get to see the original root (`$twig`'s root), so I guess the root is implicitly inherited as part of the object. I think that that's where most of my confusion lies: `root` of the special `$_` is actually the root of `$twig` and not the root of the sub tree itself.

What is the right way to take an input twig descendant, turn it into a twig with a wrapping structure?

Comment: (Not my DV). Can I suggest some complete example XML input would help massively in understanding what your code currently does?

Comment: You urgently need to read [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)
 and [*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I can remember none of your many questions that gave anywhere near enough information even to properly understand your situation, never mind the MCVE ideal of being able to simply copy your code and data and run it.

Comment: Do you realise that `descendants_or_self` simply returns the object element and all of its descendants? You are looping through all of these elements and, for each of them, wrapping the root node of the whole document in a `tree` element, producing something like `<tree><tree><tree><tree><tree>...</tree></tree></tree></tree></tree>`. I am sure that's not what you intend.

Comment: @Borodin Err, what. For all my recent, non-theoretical, questions I have provided input, script, expected output, and output. I did not in this case, true. As my post states /clearly/ I suspect that the issue lies in my misunderstanding of what `root` signifies when going through `descendants`.

Comment: @BramVanroy: Perhaps I've been unlucky with the questions of yours that I noticed. However you now have an idea about why this question may have been downvoted. As I said, I also think you may be misunderstanding `descendants_or_self`, as I can't see you wanting to wrap all those elements in a document individually. *"`root` of the special `$_` is actually the root of `$twig` and not the root of the sub tree itself"* Yes, because the root of the subtree `$_` itself is just `$_`. These things are very straightforward to discover by just experimenting and printing the result of various methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when trying to create subdocuments like that, I just create a new one, and insert a copied node.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new->parse( \*DATA );

foreach my $node ( $twig->get_xpath('./node') ) {

   my $new_root =
     XML::Twig::Elt->new( 'treebank', { id => "someid", c => "d" } );
   my $new_doc = XML::Twig->new->set_root($new_root);
   $new_doc->set_xml_version('1.0');
   my $tree = $new_doc->root->insert_new_elt('trees')->insert_new_elt('tree');

   $node->cut;
   $node->paste( 'last_child', $tree );

   $new_doc->set_pretty_print('indented');
   $new_doc->print;
}

__DATA__
<xml>
 <node begin="0" c="d">
   <node a="b"></node>
</node>
</xml>
```

But to address your specific points - yes, `root` does give the *document* root. It's a special case XML element, and `root` points you at the top level, because it's part of the  context of the node.

`wrap_in` is a special case for modifying a *node* but it won't work with a root node, because they're a special case. So you could (using my example above):

```
foreach my $node ( $twig->get_xpath('./node') ) {
   my $new_doc = XML::Twig->new;
   $new_doc->set_xml_version('1.0');

   $node->cut;
   $new_doc->set_root ($node);
   $node->wrap_in( 'trees', treebank => { id => 'someid' } );
   $new_doc->set_pretty_print('indented');
   $new_doc->print;
}
```

You can separate this out using the `cut` and `paste` methods of `XML::Twig`,